# Library conflict between Amazon AWS and Google App Engine (Multiple Dex Files)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

I have a LibraryProject that uses Amazon AWS with ProductionApps that use the LibraryProject (as a library).

My new ProductionApp uses GoogleAppEngine with autogenerates libraries for use in the app.  The problem is when I try to build the new app, I get the following error:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/codehaus/jackson/Base64Variant;
```

Through trial and error I found that the offending library (in LibraryProject) is is amazon-aws-sdk-1.6.0-core.jar (required to use Amazon AWS).

How can I resolve the error and still use AWS and GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your log it looks like the problem is that both Amazon AWS and GoogleAppEngine each include the same class in their library, so assuming that the offending classes are largely identical in Amazon & Google code, possible solutions are:

A. delete those classes from GAE lib, as your main project would still have access to the version provided by Amazon AWS, or

B. extract those classes into its own jar and delete them from both versions, or

C. if the related GAE libs are auto-generated by Eclipse plugin, extract them from GAE into its own jar (but don't delete them from GAE lib), and have Amazon AWS lib project reference the extracted jar (but don't export it)

Comment: Looks like (C) is what would be necessary however it sounds like more effort than it's worth.  I also don't see how I can make the aws-core lib reference the extracted jar.  I'll just modify the app to remove AWS completely.

Comment: I've only had some experience with GAE and not Amazon AWS, but presumably you are including some AWS related jars in your library project, so (C) would mean that you would open AWS jars and delete duplicating classes from them, and move those classes into another jar, which you don't export (set in the project setting) - the goal is to remove duplicate classes. This way the library project would still find the required classes, and yet ADT wouldn't complain of multiple definition when building the main project. Depending on your need, removing AWS is probably the quickest way.

Comment: @easycheese, if you'd still like to use AWS, you can also use the no-third-party version of the core jar and supply the additional dependencies outside of Jackson. Also, if you update to the latest version of the AWS SDK (v 1.7.1.1) it uses an updated version of Jackson that uses a different namespace.

Comment: @easycheese if AWS has updated Jackson to a different namespace it just may resolve your problem altogether.

Comment: @bob & kai thanks for the info! I did a work apps already for one app but will absolutely use your info in another.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting android-support-v4.jar file. I believe Amazon or Google will take care of it. If that doesn't work let me know so I can figure.

Comment: I doubt this is it.  The android-support-v4 jar file existed prior to the addition of GAE (the apps worked perfectly until I added GAE).  Also, I tried deleting it and the same error occurred.